# Get JProperty from Json Path in Newtonsoft.JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON path string. Let's say for example:
`Property1.Item2` and source JSON of

```
{
  Property1 {
    Item1: "Value123",
    Item2: "Value111"
  }
}
```

and fetch like so

```cs
var property = loadedJson.SelectToken(jsonPath);
// property in this case would be a JValue whose value is "Value111"
```

I want to select the JProperty pointed to by the path. It currently grabs only the value (JValue). This seems like it would be straight forward, but I cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After selecting the value token you can use [`Parent`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Parent.htm) to navigate to the property:

```
var property = (JProperty)loadedJson.SelectToken(jsonPath)?.Parent;
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lmbEGb